# List array object value on view from Meteor user collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have following Meteor user account document:

```json
{
    "_id":"aaaa",
    "profile":{
        "friendlist":[
            {"userId":"bbbb"},
            {"userId":"cccc"},
            {"userId":"dddd"}
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to iterate userId from friendlist array on my view which would look like this:

```
Friends List: bbbb, cccc, dddd
```

The html would look i suppose like following:

```
<template name="friendListCard">
    Friends List: 
    {{#each searchFriendList}}
        {{profile.friendlist.userId}},
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

and the template.helper like the following:

```
Template.friendListCard.helpers({
    searchFriendList: function(){
        Meteor.users.find({_id:Meteor.userId()})
    },
});
```

I just can't seem to make this happen.  Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the array from your helper and then iterate over it:

```
<template name="friendListCard">
Friends List: 
{{#each searchFriendList}}
  {{userId}},
{{/each}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.friendListCard.helpers({
  searchFriendList: function(){
    return Meteor.users.findOne(Meteor.userId()).profile.friendlist;
  },
});
```

Also from a modeling pov, if you only have the `userId` in your `friendlist` array then you can just have an array of strings instead of an array of objects.

```
friendlist: ["bbbb","cccc","dddd"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.  I followed your suggestion for modeling the document.  Just to make a note:  when using array, use {{this}} to display the array items to the view.

Comment: Yes exactly, your template would have to change.